# Menu Items in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need to figure out a way to change all the menu item urls in Active Admin. It seems that the rest of active admin correctly links to [app]/admin/[final link], however the menu items in Active admin simply link to /admin/[final link]. I cannot figure out how to change the url's for the menu items in order to follow the same convention as the rest of activeAdmin i.e [app]/admin/[final link].

Changing the scope/namelink in routes does not work.

Comment: just the domain where my rails app is deployed under.
So www.home.com/app/admin/[final link].
Instead of www.home.com/admin/[final link]

Comment: What is root link? Never heard of such thing in Rails. You mean the domain?

Comment: `config.default_namespace = :something` in active_admin.rb initializer is what are you looking for?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue because every link in activeadmin seems to acknowledge the the rails project is under www.home.com/app/admin

Only the menu items seem to not acknowledge that. Therefore the generate www.home.com/admin/ links.

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time on this, I think I have found a way to change the menu items urls. You can go into the resource file under app/admin in your project and add this...
Lets say the menu item is for www.home.com/app/admin/posts

> ```
> ActiveAdmin.register Post do
>     menu :url => "/app/admin/posts" 
> end
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can pass proc to menu url

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
      menu url: proc{ admin_posts_path }
   end
```

Reference: https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/8d3e9507-f612-4b42-a060-09e9aafebf0b/y